# jQuery equivalent in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building JS calculator as per `freecodecamp` front end track. My problem is that I have an idea how this can be implemented by using jQuery, but having problems with turning it into pure javascript .

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/MoXROe

**jQuery**:

```
 $("#clear,#clearall").click(function(){
      number = "";
      totalNumber.text("0");
      if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
          newNumber = "";
      } 
  }
```

I'm trying this, but it doesn't work

```
["clear", "clearAll"].forEach.call(function(e){
        e.addEventListener("click", function(){
            totalNumber.textContent = "0";
        });
    });
```

**js:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log("DOM OK");

    // Declare variables for number, new number and operators

    var number = "";
    var newNumber = "";
    var operator = "";

    // Declare variable total number to display total on the calculator's display

    var totalNumber = document.getElementById("total");
    totalNumber.textContent = "0";

    // Testing if number displayed is longer than 6 digits and if it is - Err to be displayed
    var testNumLength = function(number) {
        if (number.length > 6) {
            number = "";
            totalNumber.textContent = "Err";
        }
    }


    document.getElementById("numbers").addEventListener("click", function(e){
        number += e.target.textContent;
        totalNumber.textContent = number;
        testNumLength(number);
    })

    var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
    var clearAll = document.getElementById("clearall");

})  

   ["clear", "clearAll"].forEach.call(function(e){
        e.addEventListener("click", function(){
            totalNumber.textContent = "0";
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com). It doesn't have the equivalent of everything, but it is very useful. --- Also, your "VanillaJS" version is not equivalent to the jquery example.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: See, this is my problem. I've been using jQuery for so long that I'm not able to write any code in pure javascript. This is embarrassing, so I basically have to learn javascript again.

Comment: @freedomn-m whilst I understand what you're saying, I can't agree. jQuery isn't automatically the best tool for the job. It's certainly a good tool, but it's always good to learn native DOM interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has some wrong assumptions about how `forEah` works

```
["clear", "clearAll"].forEach.call(function(e){
    e.addEventListener("click", function(){
        totalNumber.textContent = "0";
    });
});
```

1. Every array has `forEach`method inherited from `Array.prototype` so you don't need to use `forEach.call`
2. `["clear", "clearAll"]` is an array of strings (not DOM elements) so you need to either construct an array of DOM elements or get those elements by id inside `forEach` method.

Pick one of the following options

Select elements by id and iterate

```
var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
    var clearAll = document.getElementById("clearall");

})  

   [clear, clearAll].forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener("click", function(){
            totalNumber.textContent = "0";
        });
    });
```

or iterate over `NodeList` you get from `querySelectorAll`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#clear, #clearAll'), function(el) {
 ...
})
```

or iterate over ids and get element by id

```
['clear', 'clearAll'].forEach(function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', ...)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Yury, the explanation is very clear and helps, but neither of them work. By clicking on C or AC on calculator - nothing happens.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/LLBBGY?editors=1111 check console binding works. "nothing happens" is not related to how you add event listener but to the listener logic itself.